# Pear error "XML Extension not found" on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing php-xml & php-xml7.0

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, pear, pecl

I wanna use the pecl command to install redis to my php on Ubuntu 14.04. But my Pear is giving me a list of warnings:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 173

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 139

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
XML Extension not found
```

Last line gives me this message

> XML Extension not found

, although I installed `#sudo apt-get install php-xml php7.0-xml`. But the same problem still occurs.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Also please do show us the code where those errors are on. We cannot guess.

Comment: I have encountered this issue recently on my local machine, I think it is related to incompatibilities between hte `php7.0` package and `php5-pear` (I was using the 'dotdeb' repository and had pretty similar problems)

Comment: @vuryss wut? These errors are shown when the OP is issuing `pear` command from terminal. There is no code involved in the question

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov Yes I'm getting this error while using this command : "sudo pecl install redis".

Comment: Yea I overlooked the lines. My bad. I doubt most of the pear libs are updated for php7.

Comment: @vuryss it is an error with pear itself, also `redis` extension builds just fine for PHP7 (use it in a deployed docker image) also many(majority of popular ones) of the extensions are compatible with PHP7

Comment: Also reinstalling pear doesnt work so it has to be a php error I think

Comment: Make sure the pear version is 1.10.x

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On some installations, there is a bug in pecl. Find this line;

```
exec $PHP -C -n -q $INCARG -d date.timezone=UTC -d output_buffering=1 -d variables_order=EGPCS -d safe_mode=0 -d register_argc_argv="On" $INCDIR/peclcmd.php "$@"
```

remove the -n

If you want to script it, try:

```
sed -i "$ s|\-n||g" /usr/bin/pecl
```

Comment: Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the same issue. Removed "-n" from pecl file and warnings were fixed. Thank you richp10!

Comment: Thank you... it worked in Ubuntu 16.04.4 with PHP 7.1 (+deb.sury.org).

Comment: Current PHP version: 7.2.16-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1. doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Thanks. This worked on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Answer (score 31):

Install this list and everything will work fine :)

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear pkg-config libbson-1.0 libmongoc-1.0-0 php-xml php7.0-xml php-dev
```

Comment: That is mucho O_o

Answer (score 16):

Was Facing this issue, i just needed to install php-xml

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Credits: [Taha EL BOUFFI](https://serverfault.com/a/769490)

Full Explanation as to why can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/612038)

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is not exactly an answer to the original questions, but this might be more relevant now and in the future.

One of the possible reasons for this kind of error in more modern Ubuntu versions (like 20.04) is the possibility of having more than one version of PHP installed in the system.

Even if you install only 7.x version, and 7.x plugins and f.ex. some HTTP server like Apache it does not mean that there won't be another PHP installed. It might be installed either initially (for example in docker base image) or as a dependency of something else.

I've had such a problem in a legacy docker container which used to build and work before.

The solution was to remove PHP 8.x just before PEAR install.

```
sudo apt-get purge -y `apt list --installed | cut -d/ -f1 | grep php8 | awk '{print $1}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge -y `dpkg -l | grep php8 | awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```