# How to Install mcrypt PHP module

Tags: php, linux, installation, mcrypt

I am using Linux Mint 19.1. My PHP configuration is like below

[image]

I am getting below error while I am trying to install **mcrypt**.

[image]

Comment: Does it end with "XML Extension not found"?

Comment: Thanks @showdev. Yes,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGnke.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pear error "XML Extension not found" on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing php-xml & php-xml7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999752/pear-error-xml-extension-not-found-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-installing-php-xml). Also see [PECL command produces long list of errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors) and [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: Thanks @showdev. I am getting this error    https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9TM6.png

Comment: @showdev, I am getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaf3R.png

Answer (score 1):

Try out using these commands

To install the dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

Once the dependencies have been installed, you can install mcrypt with the command:

```
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks @Simran Munot. I am getting this output   https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR0H2.png

Comment: There is an error with the PHP version. Your Installed version is 7.4 but mcrypt requires 7.2 version. Try rolling down the version to 7.2.

Comment: Thanks @Simran Munot. How can I fix that ? Thanks.